# Group multiple views in Constraint Layout to set only one click listener

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have got multiple views in a Constraint Layout. Those multiple views are made out of multiple `ImageView`s and `TextView`s. I want to give them, as a whole, only one click listener that triggers something. For example:

[image: Views in Constraint Layout]

With the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_with_shadow">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        style="@style/CustomIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/mic_icon_foreground" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        style="@style/CustomIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/mic_icon_foreground" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/RemindHint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/SummaryHint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        style="@style/CustomIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/calendar_icon_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:text="Mon, Sep 19, 2016"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Mon, Sep 19, 2016"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:text="12:25 AM"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:text="One-time event"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/close_icon_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/close_icon_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        style="@style/CustomIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/alarm_icon_foreground" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        style="@style/CustomIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/repeat_icon_foreground" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/arrow_icon_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#555"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/save"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#dd4b40"
        android:text="save"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cancel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How do I make it so that when I click the area indicated by the green rectangle (`Remind me to..` rectangular area), a click listener fires? Also, notice that there is a little space between the `ImageView` and `TextView` (indicated by the green paints). Can I group them so that their "click area" becomes one large rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either place the `ImageView` and the `EditText` together in one `ViewGroup` and set a `View.OnClickListener` on the `ViewGroup`.

Or use just the `EditText`. Set the drawable from the `ImageView` as `android:drawableStart="@mipmap/mic_icon_foreground"` for the `EditText` and control the distance between drawable and text with `android:drawablePadding="24dp"`

Comment: I see. I did think of using another Constraint Layout inside another Constraint Layout. However, I hesitated because the original purpose of a Constraint Layout is to make Views flat. Now I'm nesting again. I guess that it's not a bad-practice to nest a Constraint Layout then?

Comment: @Richard - the inner ViewGroup does not have to be a ConstraintLayout, something like a FrameLayout could work as well. That being said, I'd prefer the second solution to avoid nested ViewGroups if this is possible with the type of drawable you are using. Yet another option (although maybe a bit hacky): let the ImageView cover the whole width of the green rectangle and let the drawable appear just on the left side (`android:scaleType="fitStart"`)

Comment: That is indeed hacky. Unfortunately, though, I will be using three Image Views and three TextViews. I will need to group a total of six views. I guess that the second solution won't work that way.

Comment: @Richard - as long as you want to have pairs of image and text it will work. EditText is a subclass of TextView and the attributes are in fact Textview attributes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are so many ways to achieve this. The best one would be to make a root view that contains the imageView and the EditText and add a clickListener to it like this
add all the referenced_ids that you want to group and add a click listener to it.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
     android:id="@+id/group"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:visibility="visible"
     app:constraint_referenced_ids="yourid1, yourid2" />
```

Comment: I tried adding said Group, but in my Design tab of the xml, the constraintGroup is just a grey rectangular area with the word androidx.constraintLayout...Group. Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Group` constraint for that. Then in code you will have to get the list of ids of that group and set `clicklistener` iterating them. Not a good approach for multiple views but there is no other way around it for now.

```
Group group = findViewById(R.id.group);
int ids[] = group.getReferencedIds();
for (int id : ids) {
    findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // your code here.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this method only add a listener to each View programmatically? Additionally, I think that this doesn't solve the margin problem I mentioned (clicking on the space between the two Views).

Comment: oh yes! Good catch. You can introduce a root layout then but that will deepen the layout hierarchy. Try using the left/right drawable to the view if that is applicable to your use-case

Answer (score 1):

You can achive the expected behaviour using **Layer** which came with Constraint Layout 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Layer
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/layer_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView,editText2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    style="@style/CustomIcon"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/mic_icon_foreground" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    style="@style/CustomText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/RemindHint"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Remember that if you want to properly set background of the layer, you have to put the layer on above of all its children.

In your fragment or activity:

```
binding.layer1.setOnClickListener {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put both of these view in a `LinearLayout` with orientation set to horizontal and set the click listener on the `LinearLayout` instead.

Like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:onClick = "someFunction">

    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

    <EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the activity you create the `someFunction()` method

```
public void someFunction (View view)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Now when you you click anywhere in that row it will trigger the `someFunction` method.